# 3 outlets not working

Tags: electrical

When I was pulling my kindle from wall outlet the metal plate hit metal on the connector to the kindle. Metal on metal and their was a spark. I had an Electrician come over and he noticed 3 outlets that were mostly likely on the same grid that were not working. He changed out the outlet and put a ceramic rather than metal cover.  Then he turned the tripped breaker from off to on.  I don't know why I did not check to see if the 3 outlets worked.

I plugged my phone to charge into the newly fixed outlet and by morning my battery was dead and I checked all 3 outlets by plugging a lamp and no light. So what next?

I would appreciate any information.

Comment: On the assumption that the electrician left it in working order, are you sure the light you tested with works (eg, works in other outlets)? Is the breaker currently tripped? If so, you need to reset it and if it happens again, figure out what's tripping it. Is one of the outlets a GFCI outlet that needs to be reset (it will have reset and test buttons, and "reset" will be sticking out)?

Answer (score 1):

Double check to make sure that the breaker didn't trip again. Were the outlets working after the electrician finished or did he just figure he got it right and left?

Call back the electrician.